# Convert extract seems to extract less than it should

Tags: imagemagick, png, extract

I want to extract a specific area from a png-Picture. So I read the manual and I choose to pick imagemagick. Everything was working for 3 years, now I face some problems. I made the following:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-8 Q16 x86_64 20180723 https://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib


mischka@enot:/tmp/testgelaende$ identify newmap.png 
newmap.png PNG 2224x3255 2480x3508+130+90 8-bit sRGB 5.70104MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
mischka@enot:/tmp/testgelaende$ convert -extract 2025x2902 /tmp/testgelaende/newmap.png /tmp/testgelaende/target.png
mischka@enot:/tmp/testgelaende$ identify target.png 
target.png PNG 1983x2902 2211x3128+116+80 8-bit sRGB 5.70448MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I expectet the target.png to have the given dimensions 2025x2902 and I have absolutely no idea, what the hell is going on. Did I use the extract incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
convert target.png -strip target.png
```

I have figured out, the additional dimensions are a problem, and -strip deletes them.

Comment: PNG supports a virtual-canvas. You can remove that without losing all the rest of your meta data by using +repage. `convert target.png +repage target.png`. PNG has its own meta data and -strip will remove that, which might lead to warnings when reading your resulting stripped image. So try +repage and see if that works as well. I typically add +repage when reading a PNG file in any processing command. That way, I do not have to resave the PNG file.